# Apache ModRewrite rules for frontend controller AND `301 Permanently Moved`

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

### What I'm doing right now

I'm developing a backend for a customer.

Previously he mixed up the website data with files to download for friends and other purposes.

Example:

```
/public
    /somedir
        somesubdirfile
    anotherfile1
    anotherfile2
    foobar.html
    index.html
```

Now I implemented the common rewrite rules to proxy all requests to the new `index.php` of the website.

`.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine "On"

    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" ".htaccess"
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" ".htpasswd"
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" "!-s"
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" "!-l"
    RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" "!-d"
    RewriteRule "^.*$" "public/index.php" [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Fine, works.

Now I moved all the clutter into a separate folder.

```
/resources
    /somedir
        somesubdirfile
    anotherfile1
    anotherfile2
    foobar.html
/public
    index.php
```

### What I need to accompolish

... is to change the rewrite rules.

If the request doesn't match a specific file or symlink in `/public` it must be tested if it matches a specific file or symlink in `/resources`. If there's a match a `301 Moved Permanently` must be sent and the request redirected to `/resources`. If there's no match a redirect to the `public/index.php` must be done.

But I really stuck in understanding how to write proper rewrite rules in a complexity like I'm requesting.

I need some help here, please.

Answer (score 0):

You may try these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if it exists in /resources then redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/resources/$0 -f
RewriteRule .+ /resources/$0 [L,NE,R=301]

# else route to public/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(htaccess|htpasswd) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
```